# Why am I getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway" when using quarkusDev task in IntelliJ?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, quarkus, mockk

I am using Gradle 7.5, Quarkus 2.12.3 and mockk 1.13.3. When I try to run `quarkusDev` task from command line and then start continuous testing (by pressing `r`), then all tests pass OK.

However, when I do the same as from IntelliJ (as gradle run configuration), all tests fail with error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Masked thrown exception

After much debugging I found the problem. The thrown exception actually originates in `HotSpotVirtualMachine.java` and is thrown during attachment of ByteBuddy as a java agent. Here is the relevant code;

```java
// The tool should be a different VM to the target. This check will
// eventually be enforced by the target VM.
if (!ALLOW_ATTACH_SELF && (pid == 0 || pid == CURRENT_PID)) {
     throw new IOException("Can not attach to current VM");
}
```

#### Turning check off

So the check can be turned off by setting `ALLOW_ATTACH_SELF` constant to true. The constant is set from a system property named `jdk.attach.allowAttachSelf`:

```java
String s = VM.getSavedProperty("jdk.attach.allowAttachSelf");
ALLOW_ATTACH_SELF = "".equals(s) || Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
```

So, in my case, I simply added the following JVM argument to my gradle file and tests started to pass:

```kotlin
tasks.quarkusDev {
    jvmArgs += "-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf"
}
```

Comment: For gradle with kotlin dsl use this;


```
tasks.withType<io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusTest> {
    jvmArgs = jvmArgs.plus("-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf")
}
```